# Select x + y then return text string

Tags: javascript, forms

I have nine different pre-written text strings indicating time and cost of a specific travel route.  The variables are the start and end locations of the trip.

I want user to select two variables in a form, and get a result text string that corresponds to the start and end points of the travel leg - using Javascript.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p>&nbsp;</p>
      <form id="route_details" name="route_details" method="post">
        <p>
          <label for="start">Departure Location:</label>
          <select name="start" id="start">
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
            <option>c</option>
</select>
          <label for="end">Arrival Location:</label>
          <select name="end" id="end">
            <option>e</option>
            <option>f</option>
            <option>g</option>
</select>
       </p>
        <p>RESULT STRING: 00:00 - $0,000.00</p>
      </form>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have no javascript.  I am a web designer, not a developer but with a js example, I can manage.  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is using jQuery. Your question is very unclear so I've just included a general case.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var first = parseInt($('#1').val());
    var second = parseInt($('#2').val());
    $('.result').html(first + second);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5ubzhd4/)

Comment: I'm not adding number values... simply comparing the two variables and using js to choose the appropriate string.   ie: a+f, then a text string that relates to those two variables only.

Comment: All the resources to achieve what you want to achieve are available on the internet. We can't write a web-app for you.

Comment: Wow.  Sorry - just looking for example... not write a web app for me.